# slicing dataframe for rows which contain '.' using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This could be a stupid question but its driving me crazy for some time now. 
I am trying to slice my dataframe for rows which contain '.' in a particular column. It works for other conditions but somehow for '.' I dont get the desired output:

I have tried the below code:

```
d = {'col1': ['101.200', '102.300','90802','100,236'], 'col2': [3, 4,5,7]}
ff = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
ff
```

Output:

```
col1    col2
101.200 3
102.300 4
90802   5
100,236 7
```

When I slice with '.':

```
a = ff[ff['col1'].str.contains('.')]
```

Output :

```
col1    col2
101.200 3
102.300 4
90802   5
100,236 7
```

But the same thing works as expected when I use ','.

```
a = ff[ff['col1'].str.contains(',')]
```

Output:

```
col1    col2
100,236 7
```

Can somebody please guide me with the issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Alls good, thanks a lot. It works for me!

Comment: You are welcome, nice day!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need escape `.` because special regex metacharacter for match any character:

```
a = ff[ff['col1'].str.contains('\.')]
```

Or set `regex=False` for not read `.` as `regex`:

```
a = ff[ff['col1'].str.contains('.', regex=False)]
print (a)

      col1  col2
0  101.200     3
1  102.300     4
```